# using c++ Boost in a makefile

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, clang, clang++

I have a simple C++ program which I compile with clang using the [Boost](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.tar.gz) library and with C++14 support.

I use the following command to compile my sample.cpp file and it works fine:

```
clang++ -g -std=c++1y -I$BOOST_ROOT sample.cpp -o sample
```

where $BOOST_ROOT is the path to where I downloaded and extracted the boost zip file.

```
$BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_66_0/
```

When I try to compile the same sample.cpp file with a makefile, it doesn't work.

This is what my **makefile** looks like:

```
sample: sample.cpp
    clang++ -g -std=c++1y -I$BOOST_ROOT sample.cpp -o sample
```

Running **make** command, I get the error:

```
Sample.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'boost/format.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/format.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

And here is the sample.cpp

```
//
//  sample.cpp
//  
//

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your first name: " << std::endl;
    std::string firstName;
    std::cin >> firstName;

    std::cout << "Enter your surname: " << std::endl;
    std::string surname;
    std::cin >> surname;

    auto formattedName = str( boost::format("%1% %2%"s) % firstName % surname );
    std::cout << "You said your name is: " << formattedName << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
MacBook-Air:Listing_1_7 userd43f$ make
c++     sample.cpp   -o sample
sample.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'boost/format.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/format.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [sample] Error 1

MacBook-Air:Listing_1_7 userd43f$ ls $BOOST_ROOT 
INSTALL     boost       boost.png   bootstrap.sh    index.html  rst.css
Jamroot     boost-build.jam boostcpp.jam    doc     libs        status
LICENSE_1_0.txt boost.css       bootstrap.bat   index.htm   more        tools
```

Comment: Variables in make are expanded like this `$(VARNAME)`.

Comment: makes no difference with or without parenthesis. I tried it, the result is the same

Comment: why are people down voting this valid question? it's so absurd

Comment: Because you used 'using namespace std'.  Some people are really picky, even when it doesn't concern the problem at all.

Comment: @ChrisPy they already downvoted before i posted the sample code

Comment: Show your command line as displayed by `make` and show the directory structure of `/usr/local/boost_1_66_0`.

Comment: Looks like it does not use your rule for `sample` at all because `-g -std=c++1y -I${BOOST_ROOT}` options are missing in `make` output.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thank you for pointing that out. 
The problem was that there was a space in my makefile command line. 
I switched to tab and then it started working. And also i had to switch back to BOOST_ROOT instead of BOOST_INC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were spaces instead of a tab in the command-line of my makefile.

```
BOOST_ROOT := /usr/local/boost_1_66_0
BOOST_INC := ${BOOST_ROOT}/include

sample: sample.cpp
    clang++ -g -std=c++1y -I$(BOOST_ROOT) sample.cpp -o sample
```

In the last line just before clang++ command I was using spaces instead of a TAB. I replaced all the spaces with a single TAB before clang++, and also I needed to put the BOOST_ROOT inside the parentheses as (mentioned by @MaximEgorushkin)

Then it started picking up the right command, as shown in the output below:

```
MacBook-Air:Listing_1_7 userd43f$ make
clang++ -g -std=c++1y -I/usr/local/boost_1_66_0 sample.cpp -o sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Boost root directory normally has `include` and `lib` directories in it.

It should probably be:

```
BOOST_ROOT := /usr/local/boost_1_66_0
BOOST_INC := ${BOOST_ROOT}/include

sample: sample.cpp
    clang++ -g -std=c++1y -I${BOOST_INC} sample.cpp -o sample
```

Comment: thanks, but still doesn't work: 

Sample.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'boost/format.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/format.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @revolutionary Show your command line as displayed by `make` and show the directory structure of `/usr/local/boost_1_66_0`.

Comment: Okay, I have added the console output for the above makefile in the new edits on the post above